# Select random rows in MySQL after selecting x items

Tags: mysql

I have a query that lists the 16 most popular items in a query:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z FROM TABLE ORDER BY PCS DESC LIMIT 16
```

When I add

```
SELECT X, Y, Z FROM TABLE ORDER BY PCS DESC, RAND() LIMIT 16
```

only the items with the same PCS value are randomly ordered. So if the PCS values are 3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1... then the first item with 3 is always the first then the three items with the PCS value of 2 are randomly ordered then the rest.

How can I query these 16 rows in random order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change**:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z FROM TABLE ORDER BY PCS DESC, RAND() LIMIT 16
```

**To**:

```
SELECT * FROM
  ( SELECT X, Y, Z FROM TABLE ORDER BY PCS DESC LIMIT 16 ) results
ORDER BY RAND();
```